# Install ubuntu 18.04 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi

I have an Raspberry Pi 4 - currently with Ubuntu 20.04 desktop installed. Due to some issues with some python packages, I want to install 18.04 desktop instead, which I know works.

The problem is that the official ubuntu/raspberry-pi [download](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) is the 20.04 version (do they really not provide previous relases?!). I have tried downloading an 18.04 ISO-image and flash that onto the SD-card using Etcher, but nothing happens when I start my Raspberry with that SD-card.

Using the "Raspberry Pi Imager v1.4" to flash the SD, I can only chose the 20.04 version, or to browse for a .img file, where I have an ISO-file - I cannot find a 18.04 desktop .img file to download.

Any suggestions on how to get 18.04 Desktop installed - or is the best way just to use 18.04 server and then install desktop on that?

Comment: "Some problems with Python packages" sounds like something has not been updated to Python3.   You might want to look into having that fixed instead because this will not go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS RaspberryPi images are currently moved to archive:

- 64-bit (*arm64*) -  https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/18.04/arm64/
- 32-bit (*armhf*) - https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/18.04/armhf/

Comment: You sir - made my day!